# SQL query to find a total number of a column that only includes parts of another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, unique, where-clause

How many of these orders are beverage-only **and do not include food**?

```
fact_order_id
fact_order_line_id
category Group
category Name
```

I have tried this code below, but it's giving me all fact_order_ids that have a beverage included in it. As you can see above, some fact_order_ids have a beverage and food items.

```
select count(fact_order_id)
from table
WHERE category_group in ('Beverage (specialty)','Beverage (non-alcohol)')
```

Is there a way to get fact_order_ids to just include an item (like beverage only) and not have fact_order_ids come back that food in the category group as a SQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try.  I had no idea this could work until I tried it just now.

The filter condition counts the number of `Beverage%` and compares it to the total `count(*)` within fact_order_id.

```
select fact_order_id
  from your_table
 group by fact_order_id
having count(*) filter 
         (where category_group in ('Beverage (specialty)', 'Beverage (non-alcohol)')
       = count(*) 
;
```

There's another variation that I shamelessly stole from @GordonLinoff a few weeks back that uses `avg()` of `boolean` cast to `integer`:

```
select fact_order_id
  from your_table
 group by fact_order_id
having avg(
        (category_group in ('Beverage (specialty)', 'Beverage (non-alcohol)')::int) = 1
;
```

Either should work with `like` so long as your naming convention is consistent:

```
select fact_order_id
  from your_table
 group by fact_order_id
having avg((category_group like 'Beverage%')::int) = 1
;
```

To get a count of how many such orders there are:

```
with bev_only_orders as (
  select fact_order_id
    from your_table
   group by fact_order_id
  having avg((category_group like 'Beverage%')::int) = 1
)
select count(*)
  from bev_only_orders;
```

Comment: `avg()` seems like a curious choice when you can use `min()` or better yet, `bool_and()`.

Comment: Thanks for the options! I am using PostgreSQL. For the first option, I am getting the error `Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "filter" Position`. The second option, I am getting the error `Invalid operation: syntax error at end of input Position`. The third option seems to work, but when doing a `count(fact_order_id)`, it doesn't give me a total count.

Comment: @Natasha  I added the query to get a count of the beverage-only orders.  What version of PG are you on?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Heh.  I am pretty sure I picked up the `avg()` from you.  That said, the `bool_and()` would be even nicer.

Comment: @MikeOrganek I believe Version: 08.00.0002. I am interested on how the other ways of doing this works by the options you have given me.

Comment: @Natasha  That is ancient. `filter` came around in 9.4.  I am not sure why the second one didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This works in oracle where boolean cast to integer not available

```
select fact_order_id
  from your_table
 group by fact_order_id
having avg(CASE WHEN category_group like 'Beverage%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=1
```